# Using <a> tag as a button and Modal immediately disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, frontend

I'm using <a> tag as a button like everybody else and there has been an issue.
using it as a button and using JS to get the modal pops up using the <a> button after styling it.
here is the code:

`<a href="#" type="button" class="login-form__button-link" onclick="dataValidation()">Sign in</a>`

I managed to figure this out some how by href="#" but in the real project we can't do that , can we?

Comment: Is there a technical limitation to using a button html tag instead? Also, are you using a specific framework?

Answer (score 1):

The anchor tag is trying to take you somewhere when clicked.

The # tells you that it's a fragment of the page you are on so the browser won't redirect. See [text fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments) for more info.

While you can do this, it's a better practice to use a button. Semantic html is better for seo and accessibility.

Also, using a link this way will give incorrect keyboard behavior and right click context menus. Buttons should be activated on spacebar, links aren't. You probably don't want to be able to right click and open the modal in a new tab.

Lastly, type is an invalid attribute for a tags. If you choose to stick with the a tag, change 'type' to 'role'.